# Clear Example for drush rsync exclude paths

Tags: 7, drush

I've seen many exclude path examples here on stack exchange. But I can't figure out the way to make it work.

To keep it simple :

We have two aliases @self  and @live

we have a theme called themename in /sites/all/themes/themename

in the theme folder we have a subdirectory called node_modules because of the use of gulp in our development workflow.

***How can we make sure to exclude /sites/all/thems/themename/node_modules/ when syncing with drush rsync @self @live ?***

Comment: What command what you tried already and what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**drush rsync** has an  **--exclude-paths** parameter that will allow you to exclude your node_modules directory.

Have a look at the [parameters for rsync](http://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/core/core-rsync).

You should be able to do something like :

```
drush --exclude-paths=sites/all/themes/themename/node_modules rsync @self @live
```

Because the Drush rsync command uses [strict option handling](http://www.drush.org/en/stable/strict-options/), the --exclude-paths option must appear before the `rsync` command name.